# How do curly braces affect MySQL syntax?

Tags: mysql

I accidentally put a PHP statement into MySQL:

```
select * from info where id={${intval(17a)}}
```

MySQL gave me the error message:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '17a' in 'where clause'

Why does MySQL not issue a syntax error, empty result, or show `{${intval(17a)}}` in the error message? The column in the `id` value is `{${intval(17a)}}` but mysql says column `'17a'`? Are the curly braces and dollar sign special characters in MySQL?

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89e227/1)

Comment: @chris85 yes php report same error.this one is from phpmyadmin.i'm aware php will evaluate code.but in this case i want to know why this mysql query act that way.i change image and now that is php error

Comment: @chris85 as i said i know how to fix the query.i'm aware of double quates .but what i'm asking is why mysql query like `select * from info where id={${intval(17a)}}` act that way .why it doesn't report any syntax error?why it says about a column name `17a`?why not column name `intval(17a)` or something like that?and why it say about column column '17a' at all?it not a column it's value id is the column in the query

Comment: @chris85 yes right sorry for adding php tag.thanks for the edit

Comment: The comparison is being run against the inner most value for some reason. It says column because `17a` isn't quoted so it presumes it is a column. Try `select * from info where id={${intval('17a')}}` and you won't get an error. I'm not sure what the `{${intval(` and `)}}`is doing.

Comment: I think it's something to do with ODBC escape sequences. No idea how the `$` fits in though. It can be reduced to `{$(17a)}` and still exhibit the same behaviour.

Comment: This is just straight up busted code. That it does anything is kind of scary.

Answer (score -4):

That $ sign is PHP Specific Syntax.

I think you are just looking for this

```
select * from info where id='17a';
```

Comment: I know it's php syntax but why mysql act that way.i know how to fix the query but i'm interested in mysql error report

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370426/how-does-affect-a-mysql-query-in-php - hopefully this explains it better than I can. If this is helpful mark my answer as correct please!

Comment: that's not what i'm asking as i said i know in php if i write query like "select * from info where id='$x';" then php will replace id with value of `$x`.how ever in my example i'm running query `select * from info where id={${intval(17a)}}`.so my question is not how to evaluate intval and then run the query.my question is this query report an error but i expect syntax error or empty result.

Comment: The question is `why` not `how` and it isn't PHP related. That was incorrectly tagged.